# DataGridView - Suppress all word wrapping

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, word-wrap, column-width

I'm trying to implement a DataGridView that has smaller cell width than autosize does. 
If you look really close at a autosized cell you'll notice that there is still some space that is not used to actually display the cell's content.

That's why I started to measure the content's width by myself via `TextRenderer` and then manually set the column's width.

The initial problem was that a "A" was displayed as "A..." long before the cell was actually "filled". The reason for that was `cell.Style.WrapMode` set to "nonSet". I was quite happy that `DataGridViewTriState.True` did work for that "A"-example.

But now I just noticed that if the String has multiple words ("A, B") the DataGridView tries to display the content to several lines long before the cell is actually "filled".

What I'm now looking for is either a way to delete that "padding" of the cell's content or fully suppress the word wrapping on a certain cell/column (= single line without the String's cut off).

Additionally I should admit that there are no hidden blanks on that Strings so trim has no effect at all.

**Edit:**
I randomly stumbled upon some colleagues code that seems to do kind of what I'm searching.

`StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);`

The documentation says that strings have some rectangle around them that is bigger than the string itself. If the rectangle sticks out of the writeable area the string is wrapped. That code snippet suppresses that (default) behaviour.

The only problem is that this solution only seems to work for drawing strings. I didn't find a possibility to assign a stringformat object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;

dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode to DataGridView1TriState.True
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I want the content to be displayed in a single line. So unfortunately autosizing the DataGridView's rows is no option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this code. That is working in my condition.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null)
        return;
    var s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font);
    if (s.Width > dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width)
    {
        using (
  Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor),
  backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = (int)(s.Height * Math.Ceiling(s.Width / dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```